# What is the better way to execute a code once that requires the app to be visible per app execution?

Tags: android

Is there a better way than this one to execute a snippet of code only once when the app becomes visible and only once per app execution?

I don't want that snippet of code to be executed when a Service is started but the app is not visible.

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    private val wasSnippetOfCodeExecuted = AtomicBoolen(false)

    override fun onCreate() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
            object: ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
                override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
                    if (wasSnippetOfCodeExecuted.getAndSet(true)) {
                        return
                    }

                    // Snippet of code to be executed here
                }

                // ...
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Obs.: I didn't put that snippet of code on the "Main" Activity because it may not be the first one to be opened due to deep links.

Comment: A slight simplification is to unregister once executed to eliminate the need for the AtomicBoolean.